# Deserializing YAML with root name prefix using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-yaml

I would like to deserialize a YAML file into a Java object using Jackson and jackson-dataformat-yaml.

The YAML is

```
company:
  product:
    settings:
      property: value
```

The target class is

```
@Getter @Setter
public class TargetObject {
  private Map<String, String> settings;
}
```

The code for deserializing is

```
  TargetObject config =
  new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
      .readerFor(TargetObject.class)
      .withRootName("company.product")
      .readValue(yamlResource.getInputStream());
```

I get following exception when executing this code:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Root name ('company') does not match expected ('company.product') for type `a.b.c.TargetObject`
```

Without the second nesting "product" everything works. Is there any possibility to solve this issue without touching the YAML? I've read about escaping dots as YAML keys like `"[company.product]"`, but sadly that is not an option in my use case.

Regards, Rokko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to the solution, the problem stands in the fact you are using the wrong [`ObjectReader#withRootName`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#withRootName-java.lang.String-) method in your code:

```
TargetObject config =
  new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
      .readerFor(TargetObject.class)
      .withRootName("company.product") //<-- here the error
      .readValue(yamlResource.getInputStream());
```

Instead you have to use the [`ObjectReader#at`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#at-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer-) method to select the yaml part you are interested with the appropriate `"/company/product"` path to obtain the expected result:

```
TargetObject config = 
  new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
      .readerFor(TargetObject.class)
      .at("/company/product") //<--here the new method
      .readValue(yamlResource.getInputStream());
```